# Creating new attribute

Tags: rapidminer

In rapidminer i have a data set with an attribute called address which contain property address, what i need to do is create a new attribute which will only have the last 3 words contain in each property address. ie 231 new road County Dublin Ireland what i want to have is County Dublin Ireland in the new attribute. Could anybody help me with this process as i am very new to rapidminer. I have tried to do it with the generate attribute process useing the function expression options but no success.

Answer (score 0):

There might be an easier way to achieve that, but you can use the Execute Script operator and some regular expressions. This example script will replace the values of attribute "att1" with only the last three words:

```
import java.util.regex.*

exampleSet = operator.getInput(ExampleSet.class)
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^.*?(\\S+\\s\\S+\\s\\S+)\$")
for(Example example : exampleSet){
    value = example["att1"]
    print(value)
    Matcher m = p.matcher(value)
    if(m.matches()){
        example["att1"] = m.group(1)
    }
}
return exampleSet
```

---

Edit:

There really is much easier way: Use the `Generate extract` operator with regular expression: `(\S+\s\S+\s\S+)$` You may need to adapt the regular expression to your data.